# Printing and PDF-export from LibreOffice: SVG images get rasterized in very bad resolution

Tags: printing, libreoffice, pdf

I'd like to print and export (to pdf) a document written in LibreOffice Writer which contains SVG figures. On the screen, LibreOffice displays and scales them correctly, but for PDF export (which should support vector graphics natively) and printing (to a postscript printer) the SVGs get rasterized (*facepalm*) at a very low resolution. I have tried to enable "reduce bitmap resolution" and set it to 600 dpi, hoping that telling LO a definite number for the resolution might help, but there's no change.

How do I tell LibreOffice to export and print scalable vector graphics as vector graphics or at least to rasterize them at a usable resolution?

Here's a screenshot of LibreOffice Writer (zoom level 400%):
[image: SVG in LibreOffice Writer]

This is a screenshot of the pdf exported by LibreOffice Writer (again 400% zoom level):
[image: SVG in the PDF exported by LO-Writer]

When printed from LO, the graphics looks just like in the pdf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49832). The solution is to either export SVG to EPS first (then the vector graphics will be kept, and not rasterized), or convert to a high resolution PNG before embedding in LibreOffice. See also [comment #16](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49832#c16) in the above thread.

Comment: The bug is apparently now fixed in version 4. Just upgrade!

Comment: A workaround mentioned on the bug report is to export the PDF in
PDF/A-1a mode. Embedded SVGs are still rasterised but in much higher resolution (better quality).

Comment: Still seems to be an issue in version 6+ (~9 years later), even with SVGs having no transparency.  Reading the bug reports, it comes & goes.